# Low relevancy results using Match and Natural Lanaguage Mode

Tags: mysql

I'm building a query that is used by an autocomplete function on a website. The field "term" is indexed with the Full Index type. My query should be floating the most relevant results to the top of the list. But there are some examples where the most obvious match is not given enough relevancy.

Here's one example. I have a product term "Just Believe Bird Feeder". It does show up in a search for that exact phrase. But with a lower relevancy than terms that contain one of the search words more than once (i.e. "bird tube bird feeder")

Further, searching on "believe" or "just believe" yields zero results.

What would my best solution to overcome this?

```
SELECT
term,
MATCH (term) AGAINST (
    'Just Believe Bird Feeder' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
) AS relevancy
FROM
autocomplete
WHERE
MATCH (term) AGAINST (
    'Just Believe Bird Feeder' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
)
ORDER BY
relevancy DESC
LIMIT 15
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your words `believe` and `just` are on the MyISAM [stopword list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-myisam-search-indexes). Words on that list are ignored when indexing (or searching) with the fulltext index, so you can neither find them, nor will they influence the relevance score.

The idea of a stopword list is to exclude words that are so common in english texts that their occurance bares no relevance. This feature is less useful for searching in short titles or product codes or artificial term lists though.

You can adjust the [`ft_stopword_file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) configuration setting to specify your own stopword list, e.g. set it to an empty string to disable it completely, otherwise specify the filename for your own stopword list. You need to rebuild the indexes after adjusting the setting and a server restart, e.g. by using  `REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK`.

If you cannot control the server configuration, you could switch your table to InnoDB, which uses a significantly smaller [stopword list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-ft-default-stopword-table.html).

Some additional notes:

- the fulltext index uses a [minimum word length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length), by default 4 for MyISAM and 3 for InnoDB. You may need to adjust those settings too if you want terms like "8 oz" to have an effect.
- the order of terms has no effect on the relevance in a fulltext search